# ConvertFrom-Json complains of an unterminated string

Tags: string, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that pulls data from a DLL.  The DLL returns the first 3000 characters of the JSON.  Most of the time this is fine, because the complete json is less than 3000 characters.  However, if a row returns a longer json I only get the first 3000 characters.

If I have a json that hit the cap and I run:

```
$myString = $returnedArray[$currentrow] | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I get:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Unterminated string passed in. (3000):

The proper fix would be to deal with the source that is truncating the JSON.  However, I don't have access to that source code (owned by a third party company).

Now that I have the output is this a question of just adding a string terminator? Or do I have to parse the JSON myself, figure out what it needs to correctly end the current field, and add it?

I have been trying various things to terminate the JSON string, but none have worked.  For the moment my PowerShell script is simply skipping any row that fails the `ConvertFrom-Json` line.

Comment: If the input is truncated at a fixed position, it's a futile undertaking to try to make sense of the input - you won't know what's missing, even if you _formally_ make the input valid. It makes more sense to report an _error_ if the input is not well-formed JSON.

Comment: Check what is wrong with the JSON file by using an online JSON validator, like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the JSON string yourself and keep track of any strings or nested values so you can properly terminate them once you stop receiving the values.

Here is a short example of some Json that will be hard to terminate without tracking it in the first place.

```json
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
```